# java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.sx.mcqs.model

Tags: hibernate

```
questions=dao.getNamedQueryResultList("getUnansweredQuestionsByCategory", new Object[]{strUser});



    for(Question selectedResumes:questions) {
          //do something with the SelectedResumes object
        System.out.println("Unanswered::"+selectedResumes.getQuestion());
    }
```

======================================================================      -

following error is coming:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to
>   com.sx.mcqs.model.Question    at
>   com.sx.mcqs.service.QuestionService.findRelatedQuestionsGame(QuestionService.java:142)
>     at
>   com.sx.mcqs.service.QuestionService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$cd78275c.invoke()
>     at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
>     at
>   com.sx.mcqs.service.QuestionService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f6d3276_2.findRelatedQuestionsGame()
>     at
>   com.sx.mcqs.controller.QuestionController.selectcategory(QuestionController.java:182)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at com.sx.mcqs.filter.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:86)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:147)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   com.sx.mcqs.filter.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Answer (score 3):

Your code above assumes the named query returns a list of questions, but it returns an array of objects. To return a list of questions, the query should look like

```
select question from Question question ...
```

But the query probably looks like

```
select question.foo, question.bar, ...
```

Without seeing the executed query, it's hard to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: @NamedQuery(name="getUnansweredQuestionsByCategory", query="SELECT q.id From Question q left outer join q.internalUserAnswers ua join q.internalQuestionCategories qc where   qc.category.id= ?")

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was in holiday. Yous comment confirms my answer. You're selecting IDs of questions. Not questions. The query should be "select q from Question q ...".